# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Returning 404 for every other Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core Application and one of my Controllers works fine. But every controller after that does not seem to work, returning 404.

This controller responds as expected:

```
namespace App.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : CustomControllerBase {...}
}
```

But this controller, and all others, return 404:

```
namespace App.Controllers {
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : CustomControllerBase {...}
}
```

CustomControllerBase looks like this:

```
namespace App.Controllers {
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomControllerBase : ControllerBase {
        public CustomControllerBase() {
        }
    }
}
```

And my Startup.cs looks like this:

```
namespace App {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

            services.Configure<JWTSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JWT"));
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } else {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                    );
                });
            app.UseAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for a few days and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using /api/account for the working controller and /api/user for the non-working one?  Also, is there an Index action in both controllers?

Comment: Hi, Yeah I am using api/user for the non-working controller and api/account for the working one. But I'm unsure what you mean by Index action?

Comment: @Sarah your route states that if no action is specified, then `Index` will be the default (`{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}`). So calling `/api/account` actually calls the same method as `/api/account/Index`. Do you have an `Index` method in both controllers?

Comment: Try to move *app.UseAuthentication* before *app.UseMvc*.

Comment: I do not have an Index method in both controllers, however `api/account` seems to work without it.

Comment: Can you show the controller method that gets called in `api/account`, and the method you expect to get called in the other controller? Please include any attributes.

Comment: I added an `Index` method to both Controllers and moved `app.UseAuthentication` to before `app.UseMvc` and it's working now! Thank you!